Как с помощью регулярного выражения выделить строки с шаблоном EX** и соединить через запятую?
Как на python из строки mdsd_EX1999-inter_01.jpg nm, myname mdsd_EX1129-inter_02.jpg оставить только, что начианется на ex (регистр не важен) далее 4 цифры и заканчивается расширением .jpg ?
По идеи эти строки должны быть в последовательности с разделителем (,)
Финал таков: EX999-inter_01.jpg,EX999-inter_02.jpg

Советую изучить шпаргалку по регулярным выражениям или в конце концов официальный источник
import re

text = "mdsd_EX1999-inter_01.jpg nm, myname mdsd_EX1129-inter_02.jpg"
pattern = r'ex\d+-inter_\d+\.jpg'

matches = re.findall(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)
print(",".join(matches))


text = "mdsd_EX1999-inter_01.jpg nm, myname mdsd_EX1129-inter_02.jpg"
result = re.sub(r'\bex\d{4}-.*?.jpg\b', '', text)
print(result)  # Вывод: mdsd_EX1999-inter_01.jpg nm, myname mdsd_EX1129-inter_02.jpg Что не так делаю

@Kursk3d так надеюсь понятнее идея

Спасибо, ты бог регулярок!


Финал таков: EX999-inter_01.jpg,EX999-inter_02.jpg

Предложу такую регулярку...


const v = 'mdsd_EX1999-inter_01.jpg nm, myname mdsd_EX1129-inter_02.jpg'
const r = /[^,]*(?=ex\d{4})|(?<=\.jpg)[^,]*/gi
console.log(v.replace(r, ''))



Или вот так...


const v = 'mdsd_EX1999-inter_01.jpg nm, myname mdsd_EX1129-inter_02.jpg'
const r = /ex\d{4}.*?\.jpg/gi
console.log(v.match(r).join(','))




Разве питон умеет (?<=?

не питон чуть-чуть xD

Спасибо парни!!

@Kursk3d, примите ответ, который решает ваш вопрос пожалуйста. Галочка зеленая под счетчиком
